# Métodos para limpar parâmetros da URL após uma ação

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Olá,
Estou buscando métodos para resolver um problema que tenho, como é um problema mais interno, não posso divulgar muitas informações mas vou exemplificar aqui com alguns blocos de código.

O PROBLEMA:
Eu tenho a seguinte situação: 
Eu tenho um link em uma página *(www.site.com)* que quando clicado, abre uma nova página do meu site *(www.site.com/pagina-1)* e quando a página termina de carregar ele já abre um **modal** que faz uma requisição `Ajax` buscando uma informação do **banco de dados**. 
Esse link abre a URL com um parâmetro que chama esse **modal** *(www.site.com/pagina-1?modal=open)*.

**Nota**: Quando falar em Modal, considere o [modal básico](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/modal/#verticalmente-centralizado) do [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com.br), ok?

Certo? Ainda está acompanhando? Haha. Quando esse modal é fechado (botão close do Modal) os parâmetros continuam lá na URL certo? Isso é comum, ok?
O meu problema começa exatamente nesse ponto. Eu tenho uma outra funcionalidade fora desse modal, e ele está conflitando com os parâmetros da URL. **Leia abaixo:**

Além do modal que faz requisição `Ajax`, eu tenho também *[Navs de abas](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/navs/#comportamento-javascript)* (Essas que você clica e muda o conteúdo da tab) que carregam em cada uma, um texto via `Ajax`. 
Esse comportamento de mudar a Aba é feita através do `Javascript` e usa o atributo `ID` do `HTML` para referenciar, certo?

Acontece que quando a ABA é clicada para chamar a *tab* com o conteúdo, na teoria, ele está adicionando o **#aba1** (que é o ID da aba) no final da minha url atual com os parâmetros, e por isso a aba é trocada mas a requisição `Ajax` não é feita e retorna `null` (isto é, não retorna nada, fica em branco). **Veja abaixo:**

*www.site.com/pagina-1?modal=open#aba1*

**[Site]** www.site.com 
**[Nome da pagina]** /pagina-1 
**[Parametros do Modal]** ?modal=open 
**[ID da Aba]** #aba1

Conseguiram entender? Não tem como eu fazer um código simulando o erro. Mas as informações acima deixam bem explicado o problema. Espero ter sido claro, mas é só se concentrar em cada ponto que falei que é facil de entender o problema.

Outra coisa curiosa, para levar em consideração se alguém for parar um tempo para me ajudar com uma solução, haha: Se o parâmetro da URL for válido e retornar algo para a página, as abas **Não Funcionam**, porém se for um parâmetro qualquer sem uso que não retorna e nem faz nada, as abas funcionam corretamente. Esse são os pontos.

O que eu precisaria da comunidade, são *insights* interessantes para que eu possa tenta implementar:

- Seja dicas de manipulações
- Seja códigos de exemplos
- Explicações de lógica para resolver
- Etc

A minha única ideia seria que ao fechar o modal um script do JS capturasse a URL atual e removesse tudo depois do **?**. O ponto é que hoje há 3 formas padrões de fechar o modal: Através do botão Close, através de um botão no body do modal (Fechar) ou clicar fora da área do modal. Então essa ideia não sei se daria certo.

Bom, era isso. Aos que puderem me ajudar, estarei aqui para complementos na perguntas caso haja dúvidas.

Obrigado a todos da comunidade.

P.S: Stack de desenvolvimento: Ruby, R'Rails, Javascript.

Comment: Não me parece ser tão complexo o que está precisando, e me parece que em sua questão já existe a resposta, você precisa de métodos para manipular as `urls`... Mas sem código fica difícil saber por exemplo o funcionamento com parâmetros inválidos e não com os válidos. Existem uma série de métodos para manipular as `urls`, qual irá te atender precisa ficar claro como a coisa tá... Teoricamente está tudo claro, mas na prática a teoria é diferente...

Comment: @MagicHat vou ver se consigo exemplificar com código..

Comment: @MagicHat aparenta mas não resolve... O que estou usando é o history.pushState() mas ele apenas altera a URL, não posso fazer a requisição ajax de que preciso.. Acrescentarei isso na pergunta..

Comment: Vamos lá, seu código não iria "simular o erro", ele é necessário, para se ter um contexto de algo que possa ser reproduzido, debugado e corrigido. Isto posto, sua questão se torna ampla, e sem recursos o suficiente para que exista uma resposta objetiva. Você sabe como quer que funcione, teoricamente a falha está clara, "manipular o url", entretanto o problema em si parece acontecer na requisição que está fazendo, onde é passado parâmetros inválidos (modal=open), e tem a outra parte onde diz que funciona com parâmetros inválidos...

Comment: @MagicHat, um parâmetro válido é o `?modal=open` porque ele retorna a abertura do modal na tela. O inválido é se eu acrescentar qualquer coisa depois do "?".

Comment: vamos simular uma String que tenha o site inteiro: www.site.com/pagina-1?modal=ope#aba1 (var string)

var site = string.split("/")[0];
var pagina = string.split("/")[1].split("?")[0]; 
var parametro = string.split("?")[1].split("#")[0];
var aba = string.split("#")[1]

o resto você faz sozinho, espero ter ajudado